# Determine Python 3 version for environment variables

Tags: bash, python-3.x, environment

I am setting up environment variables to detec Python 3 along with all its packages:

```
export PYTHON_MAJOR_VERSION=3
export PYTHON_MINOR_VERSION=5
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=:${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/bin/python${PYTHON_MAJOR_VERSION}.${PYTHON_MINOR_VERSION}/site-packages:${PYTHONPATH}
export PYTHON=/usr/bin/python${PYTHON_MAJOR_VERSION}
```

Can I somehow automate the first two lines based on the system instead of typing it in manually?

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `python -V`

The -V argument prints the python version number and exits.

This will display major and minor versions:

`PYTHON_VERSION=$(python -V 2>&1|awk '{print $2}')`

So major version would be:

`echo $PYTHON_VERSION | awk -F. '{print $1}'`

And minor version:

`echo $PYTHON_VERSION | awk -F. '{print $2}'`